# Create Map of functions with type arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a `Map` where the key is a "flag", and the value is a function that takes a generic type argument.

This is my attempt

```
type Flag = 'type-A' | 'type-B'
type Flagged = {
  flag: Flag
}
type MockGenerator= <T extends Flagged>() => T

const profiles = new Map<Flag, MockGenerator>()

function addGenerator(generator: MockGenerator): void {
  const generated = generator()

  profiles.set(generated.flag, generator)
}
```

Expected use of the map (not sure if this helps add context)

```
function generate<T extends Flagged>(flag: Flag): T {
  const generator = profiles.get(flag)

  if(generator){
    throw 'no generator found for flag'
  }

  return generator<T>()
}
```

Errors when trying to add Generator

> Type '{ id: string; created: Date; name: string; flag: "flow"; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ id: string; created: Date; name: string; flag: "flow"; }'.

```
addGenerator(() => ({
  id: '1',
  created: new Date(),
  name: 'Evan',
  flag: 'flow'
})
```

[playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgQwOZQLxQOSkgWgIIZQA+m2EOAQhgFBmyJJIQAmaUA3tVFAGYMBc9ZNQC+tcNACyAewDGAawDiEAHYQATgmDT16ADwAVKBAAewVcwDOQxiwB8ACgCUaO1APVqs6SsvAoYOrSPACWcBDW6GoA7lCSCGB68MgANHFySqoaWjqOTp48AK4qssAhPlAIzMzKapra6g5MdTnqgjIKtdkNToIAbtIhrJzc3r7+zd0sbJP1Os6e3IHBYREAdJYQwE1Z9SxrfKlQs635YtRFJWUVJ+aGxmYW1sm2zI6HSIIvve4cXFBjPzHXatNjLULhSxrJjbD75f4hHgOACEtx0ThG3CgwAAFkFYhgVNJgS0GrxpMVWDwdLwGDRuOduOotoV1CoSd0dIY8qJPFUaiCGg5nK4oA5MUNBBgAIwYFL-WTMrQsQQxKAAEWVznl3BUCAAthApQBRPoIFRy-4fKV8aTRGgiJxAA)

Comment: *"not sure if this helps add context"* It does! :-)

Comment: I don't understand how you plan to figure out whether the `profiles.get(flag)` will return something that actually returns the `T` the caller wants.  If it could really do this, then you want `MockGenerator` to be of type `<T>() => T` meaning it can (magically) produce any value the caller desires without having to do anything at runtime.  [This compiles fine](https://tsplay.dev/w8K5rW) but I don't see how it could possibly work (i.e., what could `profiles.set('type-A', ...`) have as its second argument?)

Comment: Would it be enough for you if type `Flagged` is returned? (e.g. [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgQwOZQLxQOSkgWgIIZQA+m2EOAQhgFBmyJJIQAmaUA3tVFAGYMBc9ZNQC+tcNACyAewDGAawDiEAHYQATgmDT16ABQBKNAD4hjFtWqzpKgM7AoYddJ4BLOBFts1AdyiSEMAAeeGQAGn85JVUNLR1jQ0seAFcVWWBXGygEZmZlNU1tdT0mArj1QRkFfNiig0EAN2lXVk5uazsHUtqWNm7CnUSuR2c3D1sAOlsIYBKYwpYJvnCofvKDUSTU9MyVVfmtCD1lpEFQpHqzJlbhjvt9sqK2Jxd3TwmmWZON4dcePQAhGs6m1uFBgAALZx+DAqaQPWo6XjSVKsHhIk40bhiYbqGbJdR7YGDDY4nJ5A5FPSGExQPSglqCDAARgwYVueMOzEEvigABFDoZ2dwVAgALYQJkAUQaCBUbOGJyZZHwNBEBgMQA))

Comment: But.. what are you trying to do?  Your `generate()` signature implies that you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlxBQN) and call `generate<{ flag: 'type-A', foo: string }>('type-B').foo.toUpperCase()` with impunity, but the chances are near zero that this will work.  I really don't think you want the generics where you have them, and I don't think you want to use a `Map` to store things (or at least not if you expect nice TypeScript typings) since it's just from string keys to functions, and plain objects work well for that (and better for typings).

Comment: @A_A I just came to a similar conclusion. That might be the best I can get. I was hoping that the caller could specify what type it expects to be returned based on the key but I can see now that there is no way for typescript to enforce that

Comment: @jcalz, I want my map to know that it has an entry with the key `flow`, and if you call the method at the entry, you'll get back `T` which extends `Flagged`. Ideally, it would extend {flag: 'flow'} since we know that it was registered as that flag

Comment: You want the compiler to keep track of the contents of each call to `addGenerator()` so that it can mutate the type of `generate()` in order to know what it'll return?  That's not really possible.  Arbitrary type mutations cannot be tracked.  I can imagine something that plays more nicely with the type system, but it's a significant refactor and forces you to use it differently.  I'll try to code it up quickly, hold on

Comment: cool, I appreciate you @jcalz

Comment: It's taking longer than I can spend right now, sorry.  I'll look at it later

Comment: So [this](//tsplay.dev/wR9MYW) is the sort of thing I'm thinking of. You'd use a builder pattern. Whether that works for you in this exact form has to do with your workflow.  You can always refactor so that you can continue adding or modifying generators as long as you always use the latest reference.  You can't mutate state like `const foo = getThing(); foo.changeState(); foo.getSomethingWithout foo.changeStateMore();` but you can use different values like `const foo = getThing(); const bar = foo.changeState(); const baz = bar.changeStateMore();`